# Share code between AWS lambda functions in node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, callback, aws-lambda

It seems it is not possible to pass around some code (containing data and functions) that is invoked as a AWS lambda function within another AWS lambda function.

For example, take this `customConfigLambda`:

```
var callbackPayload = {};

callbackPayload.fooData = 'fooFromData';
callbackPayload.fooFunction = function() {return 'fooFromFunction'; };

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    callback(null, callbackPayload);
};
```

When I call the previous AWS lambda function in another AWS lambda function like here:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({accessKey: '123', secretAccessKey: 'abc', region: 'us-east-1' });
var lambda = new AWS.Lambda({region: 'us-east-1'});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var params = {FunctionName: 'customConfigLambda'};
    lambda.invoke(params, function(err, callbackPayload) {
        if (err) {
            // do nothing
        }
        else {
            console.log('callbackPayload:', JSON.stringify(callbackPayload, null, 2));
        }
    });
};
```

Then I can see only `callbackPayload.fooData` but not `callbackPayload.fooFunction`.

How can I have some `callbackPayload.fooFunction(s)` shared between multiple other AWS lambda functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the docs on Using the Callback Parameter at:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html#nodejs-prog-model-handler-callback

It says this about the `result` (the `callbackPayload` in your code):

> result – is an optional parameter that you can use to provide the
>   result of a successful function execution. The result provided must be
>   `JSON.stringify` compatible. If an error is provided, this parameter is
>   ignored.

To be `JSON.stringify` compatible you cannot have any functions there. See the http://json.org/ to see what is valid JSON (only strings, numbers, objects, arrays, `true`, `false` and `null`).

If you want to share code between your AWS Lambda functions in a broad sense, you have to `require` the same Node module in both of them, so that you can make a common set of functions available to all of your AWS Lamda handlers. But you cannot pass around arbitrary code between them because those will not survive the `JSON.stringify`.

As a test you can try running this in the browser:

```
var callbackPayload = {};

callbackPayload.fooData = 'fooFromData';
callbackPayload.fooFunction = function() {return 'fooFromFunction'; };

alert(JSON.stringify(callbackPayload));
```

(see [**DEMO**](https://jsbin.com/qabira/edit?html,js,output))
or this in Node:

```
var callbackPayload = {};

callbackPayload.fooData = 'fooFromData';
callbackPayload.fooFunction = function() {return 'fooFromFunction'; };

console.log(JSON.stringify(callbackPayload));
```

and see the result:

```
{"fooData":"fooFromData"}
```

The functions is stripped out during the serialization process.

Of course you could do something like this:

```
callbackPayload.fooFunction
    = function() {return 'fooFromFunction'; }.toString();
```

and get a JSON result:

```
{"fooData":"fooFromData","fooFunction":"function () {return 'fooFromFunction'; }"}
```

which you could theoretically `eval` on the other end but I wouldn't really recommend it.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there was a way :) Regarding `require`ing custom modules in different lambda functions is there a way that involves plain code (i.e. no ZIP/S3 files uploaded)? Regarding `eval` I guess that works neat only when functions don't have input parameters?

Comment: @TPPZ You may take a look at the Serverless project  (formerly known as JAWS) - see this info: http://docs.serverless.com/docs/installing-serverless It may help you a lot with deploying many functions that share some common code base. As for evaling the functions, you could eval a string `"function (x) {return x; }"` and the result of eval would be a function that you could run with a parameter. I don't recommend it because it gets messy - the symbols inside the function don't get access to the original scope where it was written but the scope of where it was evaled, for example.

Comment: Ok thanks for the link and the details. For the sake of completeness, one could do: `var fooFunctionParsed = eval('(' + callbackPayload.fooFunction + ')');` then use it like `const inputX = 42; const outputX = fooFunctionParsed(inputX);`. I did not investigate that much about scopes like `this`, but for simple helper/cosmetics functions, that return a combination of the input parameters, `eval` seems the quickest solution.

Answer (score 2):

As of AWS Reinvent 2018, Amazon has introduced [Lambda Layers](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-use-any-programming-language-and-share-common-components/).

> Lambda Layers, a way to centrally manage code and data that is shared across multiple functions.

The idea is that now you can put common components in a ZIP file and upload it as a Lambda Layer. Your function code doesn’t need to be changed and can reference the libraries in the layer as it would normally do instead of packaging them separately.